# Dynamic html element as component

Tags: svelte

I want to create a header component in svelte, where I can specify which of the h1 to h6 I want as the component. That is

```html
<HeaderComponent component={h2} />
// or
<HeaderComponent kind="4" /> // for h4
```

However, the first one doesn't recognize what `h2` is, and the second seems to just boil down to a long if-else statement, that I don't like. Is there some easy way to implement this sort of thing?

The actual component is more complicated than just a simple wrapper around h1-h6, so I can't just use h1-h6 as is or use a slot, as I want to add attributes to the h1-h6 component like an id. I tried using svelte:component, but again, svelte doesn't recognize just h1.

Is there an easy solution to this problem, or do I just do a long if-else block?

Comment: There's no easy for this yet.
Watch this issue for when dynamic elements become available: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2324
Pending PR: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/5481

Comment: Thank you, great to know there is some progress on this front

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not actually possible in Svelte yet (see https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2324), there is a simple workaround that uses the built in `{@html}` function.

App.svelte

```html
<script>
    import Header from "./Header.svelte";
</script>

<main>
      <Header headerType="h1" />
</main>
```

Header.svelte

```html
<script>
    export let headerType;
</script>

{@html `<${headerType}>Hello, World!</${headerType}>`}
```

Without using strings of if statements, this seems to be the only way this can be implemented properly.

View on the Svelte REPL [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/fdb2e0d2420546d4a1e17d47c9da416c?version=3.38.2).